# Static variable storage clarification

Tags: c, static, compiler-construction, initialization

Static variables are stored in data segment of program unlike auto variables which are stored in stack section.
Suppose I write code like below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void temp();
int main()
{
    static int a=10;
    temp();
    return 0;
}
void temp()
{
    static int a=20;
}
```

Where same static variable name is defined in 2 functions. In data segment layout there will be 2 variables with same name.
Does n't this make confusion at compile/execution time? how this is avoided currently?

Answer (score 2):

Those two static variables have different scopes so they doesn't conflict, static is storage class which defines where to store the variable. its unrelated with scope of variables.

> In data segment layout there will be 2 variables with same name

There isn't any naming in data segment, variables are just identified by their addresses, not names

Answer (score 1):

Once the compiler has compiled your source file, the variables themselves doesn't exist any more in the generated code, only their *locations*.

That's why you can have two different `static` variables with the same name in two different functions.

Not that it really matters how the compiler implement it, as long as it separates variables in different scopes from each other.

Answer (score 0):

> In data segment layout there will be 2 variables with same name. Does n't this make confusion at compile/execution time?

This is where the scope of variable comes into play.

`a` in `temp()` will shade `a` in `main()` when `temp()` is running. That means when `temp()` is running the static local variable `a` is in effect. When control returns to `main` then the version of `a` in `main` is in effect.

Comment: No, there is no shadowing here. There would be if there was a global `a` declared.

Comment: @MichaelWalz the shadowing happens regardless of whether it's static or not.

Comment: Yes, `static` doesn't matter, but `a` (static or not) in `temp()` doesn't shadow `a` (static or not)  in `main()`. It would shadow a previously declared _global_ variable `a` (static or not). [Read this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) for more details.